# HttpServletResponse redirect with application/json as Content-Type

Tags: java, json, servlets, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a post request to get json from another host using the following code. But when I tested out, I got the error "Unsupported Media Type" and the browser also indicated that the content type of the redirected request is "text/html".

Does anyone have idea how to correctly set the content type of a redirected request? Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String targetUrl = "http://localhost:8080/getJson";
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setHeader("Location", targetUrl);
}
```

Comment: Also tried resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") with no luck.

Comment: Why are you setting the content type at all? It's a redirect - the browser will make another request and get another response, and it's the content type of *that* that matters.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That cleared all my doubts.